# Enable Phone Call in ListView

Tags: android, android-intent

After lot of research over internet i could not find a answer how to enable a phone call in a list view.
here is my sample code:
Suppose i have a list of 50 hospital with there phone contact detail

```
public class Medical extends ListActivity {

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bus_main);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        list,
        R.layout.rowview,
        new String[] {"title","address","phone"},
        new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3}
    );     
    populateList();
    setListAdapter(adapter);      



}

private void populateList() {
    HashMap<String,String> 
    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("title","UHS Hospital");
    map.put("address", "Street 54");
    map.put("phone", "4077000");
    list.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("title","Calvary Hospital");
    map.put("address", "Street 43");
    map.put("phone", "2362491");
    list.add(map);
}
}
```

How to enable phone call to all listview entry based on individual Phone number detail (text3) of a hospital.

Comment: i think you should implement the onLongClick listener , based on that you should create intent that will call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this method in your activity:

```
public class Medical extends ListActivity {

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.rowview,
            new String[] {"title","address","phone"},
            new int[] {R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3}
        );     
        populateList();
        setListAdapter(adapter);      



    }
    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
        if(position>=0 && position<list.size()) {
            HashMap<String, String> tmp = list.get(position);
            if(tmp.containsKey("phone")) {
                String tel = tmp.get("phone");
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+tel));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    }
    private void populateList() {
        HashMap<String,String> 
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title","UHS Hospital");
        map.put("address", "Street 54");
        map.put("phone", "4077000");
        list.add(map);
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title","Calvary Hospital");
        map.put("address", "Street 43");
        map.put("phone", "2362491");
        list.add(map);
    }

  }
```

and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

in your manifest

Attention This code does not check if the number is valid.

Comment: sir, log cat says that: method could not be invoked on item click.

Comment: i edited my post, this is a complete code, it's working with my smartphone